# How to configure Azure AD app registration redirect URLs to work for localhost and Azure deployment?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I've registered an app in Azure AD and can successfully authenticate users against it while running on localhost.

The Azure AD app's Redirect URI is set to `https://localhost:44352/sigin-oidc` and the Logout URI is `https://localhost:44352/signout-oidc`

If I deploy my MVC app to Azure the host name will be different from "localhost". Do I have to register another app for deployment or just add a second redirect URI? But what about the logout URL then - only one can be configured there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second redirect URI. [Here are some pointer on restrictions on redirect URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

Logout URI is only relevant to your application. Not the application registration.

If you are referring to the post_logout_redirect_uri, [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request) - it must registered in the redirect_uris as well:
[image]

Or if you consider the `logoutUrl` [as described in the Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest) - that is only used when you perform a **Single-sign-out of all web apps**, [as described here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out). Frankly, there are very few reasons to use the single sign out capability of Azure AD. And, it requires of course that all apps are configured for single sign out.

Comment: Second redirect URI? Interesting. How will the correct URI be picked for my local machine when debugging/testng? Do I need to add anything to the configuration?